# subtracting integer variable mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, variables

I'm trying to subtract an amount from a mysql database based on the users input in to a form. It grabs the correct value but when placing the value into the sql query it seems like it just subtracts the total value setting the value to 0.

```
public static function stockUpdateRemove($item_code, $item_quant)
{
    $database = DatabaseFactory::getFactory()->getConnection();

    $sql = "UPDATE inventory SET item_quant=item_quant-:item_quant_val WHERE item_code = :item_code";
    $query = $database->prepare($sql);
    $result = $query->execute(array(':item_quant_val' => $item_quant, ':item_code' => $item_code));

    if ($result) {
        Session::add('feedback_positive', Text::get('FEEDBACK_STOCK_UPDATED_SUCCESS'));
        return true;
    }

    Session::add('feedback_negative', Text::get('FEEDBACK_STOCK_UPDATED_FAILED'));
    return false;

}
```

That is my function that is called upon submitting the html form.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: can you give example of the value you are sending in $item_quant variable, the database value item_quant, and what results you are receiving?

Comment: `<input id="invent_input_itemamount" type="number" name="item_quant" required /><br />` is being submitted from the form and is picked up in `$item_quant` the output i'm getting is the the `return true` and then when check the database it is showing the value as `0` even if i have subtracted 1 from 100 the value shown will always be 0

Comment: Have you debugged `$item_quant` inside the method, to check it's being passed in as 1 and you don't have an error outside this method passing the full stock total or something?